# How to round the date and time in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, type-conversion, decimal

I have a dataframe with many columns and rows in csv file, one of my columns is pickup_datetime and i'm trying to round the datetime in order to count the values.

```
Pickup_Datetime         Dropoff_Datetime
2018-01-01 00:00:20     2018-01-01 00:06:44
2018-01-01 00:00:23     2018-01-01 00:31:12
.
.
.
2018-01-31 23:59:43     2018-02-01 00:21:01
2018-01-31 23:59:50     2018-02-01 00:21:43
```

I've tried different paths to change the types but still giving me an error message

```
df = data.round["H"]
df
```

---

```
Typeerror: decimals must be an integer, a dict-like or a Series
```

---

```
df['Pickup_Datetime'] = df['Pickup_Datetime'].values.astype(int)
df['Pickup_Datetime'] = df['Pickup_Datetime'].apply(Decimal)
```

I expect the output :

```
Pickup_Datetime
2018-01-31 00:00:00
2018-01-31 01:00:00
2018-01-31 02:00:00
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: In short you're wanting to round datetime stamps in a dataframe, to the nearest hour.

Comment: @AER yes but giving me an error decimals must be integers

Answer (score 2):

In order to round datetimes, use the `.dt` accessor of datetime series

```
df['Pickup_Datetime'] = df['Pickup_Datetime'].dt.round(freq='1H')
```

Comment: Well that's a lot simpler than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Refer to other answer, far simpler

Have you tried converting each datetime to epoch, dividing it by 3600 (number of seconds in an hour), then multiplying it by 3600, and converting it back to a datetime?

Epoch is effectively the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Some code that could do this (not sure how to integrate with using the dataframe):

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(round((df['Pickup_Datetime'].apply(strftime,format='%s').apply(int)/3600)*3600)
```

Might have to adjust to adhere to PEP8 standards ;)

P.S. if the dataframe picked up the datetime as a string you'll have to use apply to convert it to a datetime object first using datetime.strptime(*format*), documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)